# How to remove these spaces on both sides of the equal sign?

Tags: spacing

How to remove these spaces on both sides of the equal sign?
They're not equally spaced around the equal sign and this doesn't look nice to me.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
These conditions  $x_1=x_3$, $y_1=y_3$ or $z_1=z_2$ should be satisfied.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The digit 1 has wider sidebearings than 2 or 3, because the symbol is slimmer. Forget it.

Comment: That' s the normal spacing of a relational symbol.

Comment: I see. Probably I was overthinking about this.

Comment: These are LaTeX beauties, if you force to remove those spaces, then the output will be ugly...

Comment: never heard about sidebearings but good to know.

Comment: It is not only the side bearing. It is also the `\scriptspace` of 0.5pt that is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the spacing of a relational operator, plus some of the symbols around it being upright and others italic with a long descender.  If you really, truly, want to change it, you can give an `=` sign the spacing of a binary operator instead with

```
\mathbin{=}
```

Or even of an ordinary symbol, like a letter, with

```
\mathord{=}
```

You can also insert negative space with `\!` or a negative value of `\mkern`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept it although I'll not change it.

Answer (score 2):

It  is not a good idea, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
These conditions  $x_1=x_3$, $y_1=y_3$ or $z_1=z_2$ should be satisfied.

\thickmuskip=0mu
These conditions  $x_1=x_3$, $y_1=y_3$ or $z_1=z_2$ should be satisfied.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see, it doesn't look nice as I thought it would be.